# Getting game stats from XBox Live and PSN

Tags: web-services, xbox360, playstation3

Is it possible to get game stats (who's playing, who wins, etc) from games that are played on XBox Live and PSN? Are there any additional constraints, such as:

1. Does the game need to support some additional API?
2. Do I need to have direct access to the games servers (consoles)?

If Microsoft or Sony or even the game vendor provides the API's themselves that would be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been workig on an API

you can check it here
www.trofeosps3.com.ar/API/Psn.asmx

and here

www.trofeosps3.com.ar/trophies.aspx

Comment: looks interesting, broken URL though.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a published public API for either service. You would have to be a registered developer with Microsoft or Sony to be able to use the APIs, but I would highly doubt that they would permit their use as an external service.

Answer (score 2):

This is in the developer XDK/SDKs for these platforms. You need to be a registered developer to get access.